# How can I include cocos2d-x templates in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, templates, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/) guide which is often quoted as being an excellent tutorial for Cocos2d-x.

The problem is that my downloads for Cocos2d-x (2.2 and 3.0 alpha0) do not include the file the tutorial indicates, **install-templates-xcode.sh**.

Any idea what happened here? I did a search for that term, and nothing came up, so I'm assuming it's not hidden deeper in the files.

Out of frustration I downloaded cocos2d-iphone, and that folder clearly has the **install-templates.sh** file. I'd rather develop for multi-platform, but this simple issue is really bothering me. I simply want to be able to create an Xcode project and choose the cocos2d-x template (as is indicated in the tutorial I linked above).

See the github repositories:

[Cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/develop)

[Cocos2d-iPhone](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone)

Notice the iPhone repository has the install-templates file.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, which is usually the case. Regardless, help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It doesn't exist anymore. You need to use **create_project.py** inside tools/project-creator in terminal.

```
-> python create_project.py [params]
```

example:

```
-> python create_project.py -project MyGame -package com.MyCompany.AwesomeGame -language cpp
```

I know, it really sucks. But it's better for creating multi-platform projects.

Comment: after created project, how can I open it?

Comment: Thanks for posting this! I had the exact same problem. Why would they remove the "install-templates-xcode.sh" file?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit on how to use crate project.py ? I have same issue.

Answer (score 4):

@marcg11's answer is valid for Cocos2d-x **version 2.***. Script `create_project.py` doesn't exist in **version 3.1** anymore. You should use **"cocos"** console instead.

E.g. In a terminal go to a folder you want to create your project in and run:

```
cocos new Cocos2DxFirstIosSample -l cpp -p org.cocos2d.Cocos2DxFirstIosSample
```

You may also specify other parameters:

```
$ cocos new --help
usage: cocos new [-h] [-p PACKAGE_NAME] -l {cpp,lua,js} [-d DIRECTORY]
                 [-t TEMPLATE_NAME] [--no-native]
                 [PROJECT_NAME]

Creates a new project

positional arguments:
  PROJECT_NAME          Set the project name

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -p PACKAGE_NAME, --package PACKAGE_NAME
                        Set a package name for project
  -l {cpp,lua,js}, --language {cpp,lua,js}
                        Major programming language you want to use, should be
                        [cpp | lua | js]
  -d DIRECTORY, --directory DIRECTORY
                        Set generate project directory for project
  -t TEMPLATE_NAME, --template TEMPLATE_NAME
                        Set the template name you want create from

lua/js project arguments:
  --no-native           No native support.
```

Answer (score 3):

The `README.md` file that comes with cocos2d-x v3.2 now says to use the cocos script to create new projects:

```
cocos new MyGame -p com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d NEW_PROJECTS_DIR
```

reference:

- https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/README.md

Answer (score 1):

you can start with these templates: http://code4app.net/category/cocos2d

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look on [this](http://lancedev.blogspot.in/2012/08/setting-up-cocos2d-x-for-android-and.html) blog, its has very nice info even you can setup for Xcode 6(beta) also.

I have tested.
But one drawback is there its for Cocos2d-x 2.0 version.