# How to obtain cocos2d-x 3.1 templates into XCode 5.x?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I cloned Cocos2d-x repo from github, everything works fine but I can't find how to install the  Cocos2d templates into XCode.
I saw that people were used to use this file, located at the root of the repo:

```
./install-templates-xcode.sh -f -u
```

but it looks like this script file has been removed, any help appreciated.

edit: Still no answer to this problem, even the slightest clues could help me. Are there still templates for XCode? Couldn't get answers from #cocos2d-x irc

Comment: i think this is helpful to you.
Check this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692898/how-to-install-cocos-2d-templates-in-xcode-5/24936366#24936366)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692898/how-to-install-cocos-2d-templates-in-xcode-5/24936366#24936366

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570677/how-can-i-include-cocos2d-x-templates-in-xcode), solved my problems.

**TL;DR** : the shell script doesnt exist anymore, just use:

```
./cocos new gameName -p com.your_company.mygame -l [cpp/lua] (-d dir)
```

to create a new project, and inside the ios folder you'll fin a xcode.proj file.